# How can I create a barplot which is colour filled according to category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have just started to learn data science/ data analysis. I am a complete beginner and any help would be appreciated.

I have the following data frame

```
Ride_ID      end_station_name  member_type  cont... 21 more columns variables    
Unique ID        A              member
cont...          A              casual
                 C              casual
                 D              member
                 E              member
                 E              cont...
                 B
                 cont... 
                 approx 60 mil rows with 500 different station name
```

I want to make a barplot which shows on the x axis the top 20 station names (top as in the top 20 staions used by both casual riders and members), this barplot should be colour filled as per member type.

The Y axis should show the count of the rides from that station. How can I do this how can I count the stations ?

Comment: can you dput() your data

Comment: Please add a reproducible example - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#Data%20frames)